# Lines getting run in strange order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible. The following function seems to run in a very strange manner. The output I'm getting from my test-prints is in the order of 1, 4, 3, 2 (with an empty returnList).

This seems to suggest that the code within the interior of these code-blocks are getting executed last, which as you might guess creates some problem when I want to return the returnList.

```
var server = new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017);
var db = new mongo.Db('tdp013', server);

app.get('/getall', function (req, res) {

    var returnList = [];
    console.log("1");

    db.open(function(err, client){
        client.collection("messages", function(err, col){
            col.find({}, function(err, cursor){
                cursor.each(function(err, item){

                    if(item!=null){
                        console.log("2");
                        returnList.push(item);
                    }

                });
                console.log("3");
            });
        });
    });
    console.log("4");
    console.log(returnList);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

My question is simply this, is there a good explanation(in lack of a better word) as to why/how these lines are not getting executed in the written order?

Or alternatively, is there a way to return the returnList without doing it in the iteration?

Comment: Because you have added `console.log("2");` and `console.log("3");` in callback function, so those lines are executing when those method executed. And `console.log("4");` will not wait for `db.open` method to be executed.Hence the results are 1, 4, 3, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the asynchronous nature that node.js further fortifies through the use of JavaScript.

You're trying to read this code and reason through its execution sequentially (i.e. synchronously), but that is not how it works.

```
console.log('1');

db.open(function (err, db) {
    // ...
});

console.log('4');
```

Take the above snippet, for instance.  **You** *expect* the function in `db.open()` to complete before it moves on to write `4` to the console, but that is not the case at all.  What happens is that node will asynchronously run that `open()` method and continue on to the next code (here, that'd be `console.log('4');`).  When that `open()` method has completed running, it'll kick off the callback function defined in the parameter list.

This is async JavaScript.  You can't expect it to run the code in your editor synchronously/sequentially written like this.

Developing logic that will flow the way (it appears) you want it to flow, it would have to be refactored like the following:

```
var server = new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017);
var db = new mongo.Db('tdp013', server);

app.get('/getall', function (req, res) {

    var returnList = [];
    console.log("1");

    db.open(function(err, client){
        client.collection("messages", function(err, col){
            col.find({}, function(err, cursor){
                cursor.each(function(err, item){

                    if(item!=null){
                        console.log("3");
                        returnList.push(item);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("4");
                        console.log(returnList);
                        res.sendStatus(200);
                    }

                });
                console.log("2");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I must have simply not realized that even the functions in themselves are not synchronous. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Node.js** is asynchronous in nature and runs on single threaded event loop.

**Example:** 
Let’s say you have triggered a database query and you are waiting for query to execute and then proceed further, but in a same time what will happen to the piece of code which are not dependent on that database query, they won’t execute and wait for their turn.

Asynchronous is exactly opposite of this. While you are doing database query Node.js will continue executing code and when database query will be done, it will come back to process it.

So in your case you have added `console.log("2");` and `console.log("3");` in callback function, so those lines are executing when those method executed. And `console.log("4");` will not wait for `db.open` method to be finished. Hence the results are 1, 4, 3, 2.

So to make sure `returnList` returning correct data you have to add that in the callback method itself.

Hope this will help you to understand the problem you are facing.